# MS Access output data in Tabular form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, records, tabular

I am currently new on MS Access DBA and VBA.
What I wanted to ask is that, how can I output a set of records in tabular form?

Now I have a comboboxName, when I choose a name from this comboboxName, below of this combo box will output a table of items this person bought.

Is there something like jTable in MS Access?

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create a sub form control.  Once you have a sub form control you can either assign it a form set to datasheet view or use an existing query.  With your combo box you will want to use the `On_Change` event  to set the sub forms filter to the selected record.